# how to define a space in a regular expression (in awk)?

Tags: regex, awk, space

I want to print the texts inside of `" "`. for example I have the following strings:

```
gfdg "jkfgh" "jkfd fdgj fd-" ghjhgj
gfggf "kfdjfdgfhbg" "fhfghg" jhgj
jhfjhg "dfgdf" fgf
fgfdg "dfj jfdg jhfgjd" "hfgdh jfdhgd jkfghfd" hgjghj
```

And I want to print only the following:

```
"jkfgh" "jkfd fdgj fd-"
"kfdjfdgfhbg" "fhfghg"
"dfgdf"
"dfj jfdg jhfgjd" "hfgdh jfdhgd jkfghfd"
```

I have tried awk with the following regular expression:

```
awk '{for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if($i ~ /^\"[A-Za-z.$]*([A-Za-z.$][[:space:]]*[A-Za-z.$])*\"$/) print $i}' sample.txt
```

but it prints everything before space and actually does not recognize the spaces I have defined in my regular expression. My current output is:

```
"jkfgh"
"kfdjfdgfhbg" "fhfghg"
"dfgdf"
"dfj
```

as you can see, only the ones without any space are printed correctly.

I have also tried `[[:blank:]]`, `\t` and also `' '` but did not work.

I appreciate if someone can tell me how to change this regular expression and include space.

Comment: Do you want to print all fields except the first and the last for each line?

Comment: i want to print only the texts inside " "s including spaces.

Comment: @hketab: I think you still have misconceptions; see my updated answer for a clarification, and, if you can use _GNU_ `awk`, a solution. You should also update your question to indicate that you want to extract _single_-quoted strings too, and that it is _incidental_ in the sample data that only the _interior_ tokens are quoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple field separator single quotes ' ' and double quotes " " in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559774/multiple-field-separator-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-awk)

Answer (score 7):

The question's title is misleading and based on a fundamental misconception about `awk`.

The naïve answer is that **a space can simply be represented as itself (a literal) in regular expressions in `awk`**.
More generally, you can use `[[:space:]]` to match a space, a tab or a newline (*GNU* Awk also supports `\s`), and `[[:blank:]]` to match a space or a tab.

However, the crux of the problem is that **Awk, by default, splits each input line into fields by *whitespace*, so that, *by definition, no input field itself contains whitespace***, so any attempt to match a space in a field value will invariably fail.

The input at hand has fields that are a mix of unquoted and quoted strings, but **POSIX Awk has no support for recognizing *quoted* strings as fields**.

[@fedorqui has made a valiant attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512928/45375) to work around the problem by splitting input into fields by double quotes, but it's no substitute for proper recognition of quoted strings, because it doesn't preserve the true field boundaries.

If you have ***GNU* Awk**, you **can *approximate* recognition of quoted strings** using the special `FPAT` variable, which, rather than defining a *separator* to split lines by, allows defining a regex that describes *fields* (and ignores tokens not recognized as such):

```
re='[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:] ]*[[:alpha:]]' # aux. shell variable
gawk -v FPAT="\"$re\"|'$re'" '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n" : " ") 
}' sample.txt
```

This **will work with single- and double-quoted strings**.

Explanation:

- `FPAT="\"$re\"|'$re'"` defines fields to be either double- or single-quoted strings consisting only of letters and spaces, with at least one letter on either end (as in the OP's code).
- Note that this automatically excludes the UNquoted tokens on each input line - they will *not* be reflected in `$1`, ... and `NF`.
- Therefore, the loop `for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)` is already limited to enumerating only the *matching* fields.

---

Note that, generally, the restrictions placed on the contents of the quoted strings in *this case* luckily bypass limitations inherent in this approach, namely the **inability to deal with escaped nested quotes (of the same type).**

**If this limitation is acceptable**, you can use the following **idiom to tokenize input that is a mix of barewords (unquoted tokens) and quoted strings**:

```
gawk -v "FPAT=[^[:blank:]]+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'" ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You are just getting those without any space because you loop through fields and they are space separated. Thus, you need to change the approach to something handling the spaces differently. Assuming there are no nested quotes, you can use for example:

```
awk -F'"' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) printf "\"%s\"", $i; print ""}' file
```

That is, use `"` as field separator and print the even fields.

This is equivalent to using `FS` more elegantly:

```
awk -F'"' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s%s", FS, $i, FS; print ""}' file
```

Note in the previous approaches the output has no space in between fields. If you need it, you can use:

```
awk -F'"' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s%s%s", FS, $i, FS, (i>NF-2?"\n":" ")}' file
```

The trick `(i>NF-2?"\n":" ")` is a matter of printing the whole field together with a separator. If we are in the last field, we set it as new line; otherwise, as a space. More idiomatically, you can also say `(i>NF-2?RS:OFS)` using the default values of `RS` (record separator, new line) and `OFS` (output field separator, space).

#### Test

```
$ awk -F'"' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s%s%s", FS, $i, FS, (i>NF-2?"\n":" ")}' file
"jkfgh" "jkfd fdgj fd-"
"kfdjfdgfhbg" "fhfghg"
"dfgdf"
"dfj jfdg jhfgjd" "hfgdh jfdhgd jkfghfd"
```

Comment: + for the explanation; note that you're printing quotes in _both_ cases,  (first, hard-coded into the format string, then with `FS`); there's no space between the output fields.
If you append a space to the format string to fix that, you'll have to treat the last output field special to avoid a _trailing_ space.

Comment: @mklement0 fair point. I felt like golfing a little bit and added a solution with spaces in between strings. Thanks for the input!

Comment: yes I have problem with trailing space but not because of appending a space to the format string. I have changed the command to 'i<5' instead of 'i<NF' to stop the loop for more than two nested quotes but it still prints one  or two extra " " . can you help me?

Comment: @hketab you can maybe change the `for` definition to `for (i=2;i<5 && i<NF;i+=2)`.

Comment: @hketab: Not sure I fully understand, but if you're getting the right fields and your only problem is trailing spaces, a quick solution is to pipe Awk's output to `| sed 's/ *$//'`; a more efficient solution is to build the output as a _string_ in Awk first, then apply `sub(" *$", "", s)` to it, then print it.

Comment: I noticed that I have to consider single quotes `(' ')` as well. I have to use a regular expression including ",  ' and also spaces. I tried \s as suggested in many websites for space, but did not work. any solution for this problem?

Comment: @hketab since you are changing the requirements all the time, it might be best to start a brand new question.

Comment: i think from the beginning i asked for a regular expression including space.

Comment: @hketab `i want to print only the texts inside " "s including spaces` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512854/how-to-define-a-space-in-a-regular-expression-in-awk/29512928#comment47182704_29512854  You should also read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck.