# how to append a new tag after a matched pattern in xml using a bash command

Tags: bash, shell

**Consider that I have xml content as below:**

*Pattern to be found [say patternString]:*

```
        </secure-deployment>
        <% end %>
```

**Wished to append the below xml content after matching the above pattern:**

*Pattern to be appended* [say appendingString]:*

```
        <secure-deployment name="gvh-vid.war">
            <resource>gvh-vid</resource>
        </secure-deployment>
```

**Output should be of the format:**

```
        </secure-deployment>
        <% end %>
        <secure-deployment name="gvh-vid.war">
            <resource>gvh-vid</resource>
        </secure-deployment>
```

Tried with awk command with below syntax and it does append [say appendingString] on after each line of the matched pattern [say patternString] instead of appending the content after macthed pattern:

i.e.

```
        awk '/<\/secure-deployment>/,/<% end %>/ {$0=$0"\n            <secure-deployment name=\"gvh-wid.war\">\n                <resource>gvh-vid<\/resource>\n            <\/secure-deployment>"} 1' standalone.xml.erb
```

*Observed Output:*

```
        </secure-deployment>
        <secure-deployment name="gvh-vid.war">
            <resource>gvh-vid</resource>
        </secure-deployment>
        <% end %>
        <secure-deployment name="gvh-vid.war">
            <resource>gvh-vid</resource>
        </secure-deployment>
```

*Can someone suggest me improve this with awk command?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `awk` in detail, but I think the problem is how you do the match: using

```
/</secure-deployment>/,/<% end %>/
```

you are making an `OR`, but what you want is an `AND`, if I correctly understand your question.

So, I would replace your selection to something like:

```
/</secure-deployment>\s*<% end %>/
```

which expects the two tags to be consecutive, only possibly separated by an arbitrary number of spaces (newlines included).

---

**UPDATE**:
I just found my proposed answer does not work, and explained the reason in a comment.

So the final answer is: **you CAN'T improve your awk script to work in your use case, if not introducing REALLY awful hacks, since awk is designed to work on input one line at a time**.

I try to write for you a `perl` script to do the same job:

```
perl -0777p -i -e 's/^(.*?)(\s*<\/secure-deployment>\s*<% end %>)(.*?)$/\1\2\n        <secure-deployment name=\"gvh-wid.war\">\n            <resource>gvh-vid<\/resource>\n        <\/secure-deployment>\3/s' standalone.xml.erb
```

I grant you this is not the clearest script ever written, but it should work...

Comment: Found the problem, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29513125/709439:
`a space can simply be represented as itself (a literal) in regular expressions in awk.
More generally, you can use [[:space:]] to match a space, a tab or a newline (GNU Awk also supports \s), and [[:blank:]] to match a space or a tab.

However, the crux of the problem is that Awk, by default, splits each input line into fields by whitespace, so that, by definition, no input field itself contains whitespace, so any attempt to match a space in a field value will invariably fail.`

Comment: Glad to help... :-)

Comment: yes, I had accepted it, and is getting reflected in the score